# Custom plot with pc3

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

I'm trying to do a custom plot with design automation, but it crashes on `validator.Validate(plotInfo);` with a `eDeviceNotFound` error.

It's because the Acad engine can't find my *custom.pc3* file.

I tried to put it in the *appPackage.zip*, but it doesn't work.

Where did I need to put my pc3 file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try uploading your custom pc3 file to cloud server, pass it to Forge DA.

Sample workflow flows

- Create Activity

  ```
  {
      "HostApplication": "",
      "RequiredEngineVersion": "22.0",
      "Parameters": {
          "InputParameters": [
              {
                  "Name": "HostDwg",
                  "LocalFileName": "$(HostDwg)"
              },
              {
                  "Name": "CustomPC3",
                  "LocalFileName": "custom.pc3"
              }
          ],
          "OutputParameters": [
              {
                  "Name": "Result",
                  "LocalFileName": "result.pdf"
              }
          ]
      },
      "Instruction": {
          "CommandLineParameters": null,
          "Script": "FPDPLOT\ncustom.pc3\nresult.pdf\n"
      },
      "AppPackages":["CustomPlotter"],
      "Version": 1,
      "Id": "CustomPlotter"
  }
  ```
- Workitem Payload

  ```
  {
      "Arguments": {
          "InputArguments": [
              {
                  "Resource":"https://madhukar-fda.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Kitchens.dwg",
                  "Name": "HostDwg"
              },
              {
                  "Resource": "https://madhukar-fda.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Custom.pc3",
                  "Name": "CustomPC3"
              }
          ],
          "OutputArguments": [
              {
                  "Name": "Result",
                  "HttpVerb": "POST"
              }
          ]
      },
      "ActivityId": "CustomPlotter"
  }
  ```
- .NET Custom Command

  ```
  public static void PlotLayout()
  {
      // Get the current document and database, and start a transaction

      Document acDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
      Database acCurDb = acDoc.Database;
      PromptResult result = acDoc.Editor.GetString("Enter PC3 File:");
      if (result.Status != PromptStatus.OK) return;
      string pc3FileName = result.StringResult;
      result = acDoc.Editor.GetString("Enter PDF Name :");
      if (result.Status != PromptStatus.OK) return;
      string pdfFileName = result.StringResult;

      using (Transaction acTrans = acCurDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
      {
          // Reference the Layout Manager
          LayoutManager acLayoutMgr = LayoutManager.Current;

          // Get the current layout and output its name in the Command Line window
          Layout acLayout = acTrans.GetObject(acLayoutMgr.GetLayoutId(acLayoutMgr.CurrentLayout),
                                              OpenMode.ForRead) as Layout;
          //Here we are setting custom config file
          PlotConfig acPlCfg = PlotConfigManager.SetCurrentConfig(pc3FileName);
          // Get the PlotInfo from the layout
          using (PlotInfo acPlInfo = new PlotInfo())
          {
              acPlInfo.Layout = acLayout.ObjectId;

              // Get a copy of the PlotSettings from the layout
              using (PlotSettings acPlSet = new PlotSettings(acLayout.ModelType))
              {
                  acPlSet.CopyFrom(acLayout);

                  // Update the PlotSettings object
                  PlotSettingsValidator acPlSetVdr = PlotSettingsValidator.Current;

                  // Set the plot type
                  acPlSetVdr.SetPlotType(acPlSet, Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices.PlotType.Extents);

                  // Set the plot scale
                  acPlSetVdr.SetUseStandardScale(acPlSet, true);
                  acPlSetVdr.SetStdScaleType(acPlSet, StdScaleType.ScaleToFit);

                  // Center the plot
                  acPlSetVdr.SetPlotCentered(acPlSet, true);

                  // Set the plot device to use
                  acPlSetVdr.SetPlotConfigurationName(acPlSet, "custom.pc3", "ANSI_A_(8.50_x_11.00_Inches)");

                  // Set the plot info as an override since it will
                  // not be saved back to the layout
                  acPlInfo.OverrideSettings = acPlSet;

                  // Validate the plot info
                  using (PlotInfoValidator acPlInfoVdr = new PlotInfoValidator())
                  {
                      acPlInfoVdr.MediaMatchingPolicy = MatchingPolicy.MatchEnabled;
                      acPlInfoVdr.Validate(acPlInfo);

                      // Check to see if a plot is already in progress
                      if (PlotFactory.ProcessPlotState == ProcessPlotState.NotPlotting)
                      {
                          using (PlotEngine acPlEng = PlotFactory.CreatePublishEngine())
                          {
                              // Track the plot progress with a Progress dialog
                              using (PlotProgressDialog acPlProgDlg = new PlotProgressDialog(false, 1, true))
                              {
                                  using ((acPlProgDlg))
                                  {
                                      // Define the status messages to display 
                                      // when plotting starts
                                      acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.DialogTitle, "Plot Progress");
                                      acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.CancelJobButtonMessage, "Cancel Job");
                                      acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.CancelSheetButtonMessage, "Cancel Sheet");
                                      acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.SheetSetProgressCaption, "Sheet Set Progress");
                                      acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.SheetProgressCaption, "Sheet Progress");

                                      // Set the plot progress range
                                      acPlProgDlg.LowerPlotProgressRange = 0;
                                      acPlProgDlg.UpperPlotProgressRange = 100;
                                      acPlProgDlg.PlotProgressPos = 0;

                                      // Display the Progress dialog
                                      acPlProgDlg.OnBeginPlot();
                                      acPlProgDlg.IsVisible = true;

                                      // Start to plot the layout
                                      acPlEng.BeginPlot(acPlProgDlg, null);

                                      // Define the plot output
                                      acPlEng.BeginDocument(acPlInfo, acDoc.Name, null, 1, true, pdfFileName);

                                      // Display information about the current plot
                                      acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.Status, "Plotting: " + acDoc.Name + " - " + acLayout.LayoutName);

                                      // Set the sheet progress range
                                      acPlProgDlg.OnBeginSheet();
                                      acPlProgDlg.LowerSheetProgressRange = 0;
                                      acPlProgDlg.UpperSheetProgressRange = 100;
                                      acPlProgDlg.SheetProgressPos = 0;

                                      // Plot the first sheet/layout
                                      using (PlotPageInfo acPlPageInfo = new PlotPageInfo())
                                      {
                                          acPlEng.BeginPage(acPlPageInfo, acPlInfo, true, null);
                                      }

                                      acPlEng.BeginGenerateGraphics(null);
                                      acPlEng.EndGenerateGraphics(null);

                                      // Finish plotting the sheet/layout
                                      acPlEng.EndPage(null);
                                      acPlProgDlg.SheetProgressPos = 100;
                                      acPlProgDlg.OnEndSheet();

                                      // Finish plotting the document
                                      acPlEng.EndDocument(null);

                                      // Finish the plot
                                      acPlProgDlg.PlotProgressPos = 100;
                                      acPlProgDlg.OnEndPlot();
                                      acPlEng.EndPlot(null);
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you place the `.pc3` file under `Plotters` folder.